# Enable query service for couchbase

Tags: couchbase

Sorry for very beginner question, just installed couchbase for the first time and when I want to load the "beer-sample" to try to run some n1ql scripts I get the following:

> This cluster does not contain an index or query node. Sample data will be installed without creating indexes.

and when I click Query in the couchbase console:

> No query nodes were found on this cluster.

How can I enable these two?

Comment: You would have selected it when creating the cluster https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-nodes/create-cluster.html

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, it worked. Would you make it an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just installed couchbase for the first time

During installation, it should have prompted you to install certain services per node of the cluster.

It might be possible to add services afterwards of cluster setup, but since you have a fresh cluster anyway, I'd suggest just restarting from the beginning

Relevant documentation: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/manage/manage-nodes/create-cluster.html

Comment: I tried to find a way to enable a service after couchbase installation but it seems there is no way doing it or maybe I couldn't find it at all if there is one. In my case I desperately need it without the reinstallation.